# Can't get SSH to work over USB in linux [Raspberry Pi Zero W]

Tags: usb, ssh, pi-zero, archlinux, pi-zero-w

The problem is that I can't get it to work while using linux, I can SSH just fine into it on my Windows machine but on my laptop running arch, it doesn't seem to be able.

I've followed the steps I found online, adding dtoverlay=dwc2 to your config.txt, adding modules-load=dwc2,g_ether to your cmdline.txt and then creating a blank file called ssh, and giving that it already working on a Windows system, it's clearly not the problem.

On my linux machine, I have the avahi-daemon running and if I issue an avahi-browse -all I see

```
enp0s20u3 IPv6 raspberrypi                 Workstation       local
```

If I check my networkmanager, it shows up as an ethernet device. If I check ifconfig, it also shows up with its own interface.

Does anyone have any clue as to why it isn't working?

*Edit: The only way I've figured out how to SSH into it is by using avahi-browse -art and marking down its address and interface, then

```
ssh pi@(address)%(interface)
```

Comment: You could put your edit as an answer, that would make it clear your problem is solved.

Comment: @dmitry it's more of a compromise, I haven't figured out how to enter pi@raspberrpi.local instead of having to enter output I get from avahi.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 18.3, I have to go into Network Connections and edit the entry that shows up when the Zero W is plugged in.
Go to the IPv4 Settings tab, and change **Link-Local Only**.
After I do this, and wait about 15 seconds or so, I get a notifcation that Wired Connectiong #2 was made. Wired Connection #1 is my connection to my router; I am not on wifi.
Then I can SSH in or just ping the Zero W.